# performSelectorInBackground and performing UI Operation

Tags: iphone

In application I need to take Image out of UIView. Frame of that View is W 1800 and H 1200.

This activity takes lot time and screen stucks there unless this activity get finish.

I need to perform this activity in background,so that user can continue with other things.

What is best approach to achive this. I tried with

```
- (void)performSelectorInBackground:(SEL)aSelector withObject:(id)arg
```

But application get crash as it doesn't allow UI operation with this. If I go with

```
- (void)performSelectorOnMainThread:(SEL)aSelector withObject:(id)arg waitUntilDone:(BOOL)wait
```

screen stucks there unless this activity get finish.

I need to perform following activity in background

```
-(void) PrepareImageData
{
    UIImage* frontViewImage = [self PreparefrontImage:[self GetSavedFrontImage]];
    [self SaveImageinDocumentWithName:frontViewImage FileName:@"frontview.png"];

    UIImage* rearViewImage  = [self PrepareBackImage:[self GetSavedBackImage]];;
    [self SaveImageinDocumentWithName:rearViewImage FileName:@"backview.png"];
}
    -(UIImage*) GetSavedBackImage
    {
        UIImage* background;
        UIImage* messageTextview;
        UIImage* toTextView;
        UIImage* fromTextView;

        background      = [self GetImageFromView:self toRect:self.frame];

        CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1800, 1200);
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
        CGPoint backgroundPoint = CGPointMake(0,0);
        [background drawAtPoint:backgroundPoint];
        UIImage* backImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContex();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

        return backImage;
    }

    - (UIImage *) GetImageFromView:(UIView *)aView toRect:(CGRect)aRect
    {
        CGSize pageSize = aRect.size;
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(pageSize);
        [aView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
        UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
        return image;

    }
```

Please help me on this.

Thanks.

Comment: You need to put in more code related to what exactly you are trying to achieve

Comment: "take Image out of UIView"? What? Do you have any code to demonstrate your problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem lies with the sheer size of the view - an app attempting to manipulate a view this size in this way is probably quite likely to get killed by the OS for using too much memory, especially under iOS 4.x.  UIViews used to be limited to 1024x1024 for a very good reason.

I'd recommend looking into ways of dividing the problem up into chunks which can be processed without requiring so much memory.

Comment: Like subclassing UIView and overriding `+(CALayer *)layer` to return a CATiledLayer instead.

[CATiledLayer Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CATiledLayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Comment: Hello Andrew, can you please give me some threads to achive this type of functionality.