# calling a function on a background thread ios-what happens to the nested function calls

Tags: ios, function, uiactivityindicatorview, background-thread

In my main code(in order to show UIActivityIndicatorView) I'm calling a function, foo() on a background thread. What happens to the functions called by foo() in turn? Will those functions also be called and executed in the same background thread?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it will also be called in that same background thread.

It's actually pretty easy: everything you call will be run in the same thread as the caller, unless you *explicitly* use methods to create a new thread and run a method there or cause a method to be run in another thread (e.g. `performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:`). But from those methods on it's the same again: they will be run in the very same thread as their callers.